# Does Expo required a internet connection for React native build?

Tags: react-native, expo

So I just finish the project, detached, using expoKit. Uploaded it to the testflight. And it pops out an error message said:"This experience uses an unsupported version of Expo(v22.0.0)..." So I re-publish my project in Expo XDE and the error message gone.

Now I am just confused, dose expoKit require a user to have an internet connection to use the app in order to download data from expo server?

What does expo really do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, expo required internet connection, it will generate link and you need to open it in your device to see output

from it's doc

Expo apps are React Native apps which contain the Expo SDK. The SDK is a native-and-JS library which provides access to the device's system functionality (things like the camera, contacts, local storage, and other hardware). That means you don't need to use Xcode or Android Studio, or write any native code, and it also makes your pure-JS project very portable because it can run in any native environment containing the Expo SDK.

for more please see https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/ and https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/up-and-running.html

Answer (score 3):

you need to clear cache and storage in setting in emulator for expo.
in ur emulator go to settings/apps/expo/storage/clear...
it will work right now.
br